# How to Convert sql query to Laravel query builder format

Tags: php, laravel

How to Convert sql query to Larvel query builder format

**Here is Query**

```
"SELECT `id`, `name`, `phone`, `latitude`, `longitude`, SQRT( POW(69.1 * (`latitude` - 24.900363), 2) + POW(69.1 * (67.099760 - `longitude`) * COS(`latitude` / 57.3), 2)) AS `distance` FROM `users` HAVING `distance` < 25 ORDER BY `distance`";
```

Comment: Using the [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries). Feel free to ask if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: please can you convert this query into laravel format

Comment: like this   $users = DB::table('users')
        ->select('name','phone','latitude','longitude')
        ->SQRT("POW(69.1 * (latitude - 24.900110), 2) +
        POW(69.1 * (67.099760 - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance")
        ->having("distance < 25")
        ->orderBy("distance")
        ->get();

Comment: If that is your attempt to convert it please a) add it to your question, not comments (you can use the "edit" button under your question), and b) explain what specific problem you are experiencing when you run it. Then we have got an actual problem to solve (not just "please do my work for me") :-).

Comment: P.S. AFAIK the query builder does not have a method called "SQRT" (it certainly isn't in the documentation anyway - did you check??), so I'd expect that is likely to be the issue. But really, you should tell us specifically, rather than rely on people to guess or just start over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can give this a try like this

```
$results = Users::select(['id','name','phone','latitude','longitude', DB::raw('SQRT( POW(69.1 * (`latitude` - 24.900363), 2) + POW(69.1 * (67.099760 - `longitude`) * COS(`latitude` / 57.3), 2)) AS distance')])->havingRaw('distance < 25')->OrderBy('distance')->get();
```